# TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'entries' (IE11)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11, aurelia

I have an app written in Aurelia which needs to run in IE11.

Until last week the app was running ok but now I get the following error in the console when I try running it

```
TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'entries'
```

I have no idea what's caused this. I've gone back commits to a month ago, where the app was definitely working in IE11, but I get the same error.

We are using `Yarn` for package management with `Webpack`

The full stack dump is:

```
{
   [functions]: ,
   __proto__: { },
   __symbol:__symbol:rxSubscriber0.6484791277649529: undefined,
   __symbol:hasInstance0.64847912776495296: undefined,
   __symbol:isConcatSpreadable0.64847912776495297: undefined,
   __symbol:iterator0.64847912776495291: undefined,
   __symbol:match0.64847912776495292: undefined,
   __symbol:replace0.64847912776495293: undefined,
   __symbol:search0.64847912776495294: undefined,
   __symbol:species0.64847912776495299: undefined,
   __symbol:split0.64847912776495295: undefined,
   __symbol:toPrimitive0.648479127764952910: undefined,
   __symbol:toStringTag0.648479127764952911: undefined,
   __symbol:unscopables0.64847912776495298: undefined,
   description: "Object doesn't support property or method 'entries'",
   message: "Object doesn't support property or method 'entries'",
   name: "TypeError",
   number: -2146827850,
   stack: "TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'entries'
   at createSelectors (http://localhost:51158/dist/app.js?v=Q8Lj1h7qjQUyqYO52tjHs-75tv3cmxHiL7p-24hxcAM:28145:9)
   at target.prototype[] (http://localhost:51158/dist/app.js?v=Q8Lj1h7qjQUyqYO52tjHs-75tv3cmxHiL7p-24hxcAM:28176:13)
   at bind (http://localhost:51158/dist/app.js?v=Q8Lj1h7qjQUyqYO52tjHs-75tv3cmxHiL7p-24hxcAM:36702:7)
   at bind (http://localhost:51158/dist/app.js?v=Q8Lj1h7qjQUyqYO52tjHs-75tv3cmxHiL7p-24hxcAM:38733:7)
   at automate (http://localhost:51158/dist/app.js?v=Q8Lj1h7qjQUyqYO52tjHs-75tv3cmxHiL7p-24hxcAM:38678:5)
   at ready (http://localhost:51158/dist/app.js?v=Q8Lj1h7qjQUyqYO52tjHs-75tv3cmxHiL7p-24hxcAM:48132:7)
   at swap (http://localhost:51158/dist/app.js?v=Q8Lj1h7qjQUyqYO52tjHs-75tv3cmxHiL7p-24hxcAM:48161:5)
   at Anonymous function (http://localhost:51158/dist/app.js?v=Q8Lj1h7qjQUyqYO52tjHs-75tv3cmxHiL7p-24hxcAM:48682:9)
   at Anonymous function (http://localhost:51158/dist/app.js?v=Q8Lj1h7qjQUyqYO52tjHs-75tv3cmxHiL7p-2"
}
```

I've tried looking at other SOF posts but I haven't been able to find a clear answer on what I should do - can anyone help?

Edit:

I just installed [this polyfill](https://yarnpkg.com/en/package/@riim/object-entries-polyfill) and ran Webpack and now I'm getting this error:

```
ERROR [app-router] SyntaxError: Syntax error
   "ERROR [app-router]"
   {
      [functions]: ,
      __proto__: { },
      __symbol:__symbol:rxSubscriber0.7605681080912143: undefined,
      __symbol:hasInstance0.76056810809121436: undefined,
      __symbol:isConcatSpreadable0.76056810809121437: undefined,
      __symbol:iterator0.76056810809121431: undefined,
      __symbol:match0.76056810809121432: undefined,
      __symbol:replace0.76056810809121433: undefined,
      __symbol:search0.76056810809121434: undefined,
      __symbol:species0.76056810809121439: undefined,
      __symbol:split0.76056810809121435: undefined,
      __symbol:toPrimitive0.760568108091214310: undefined,
      __symbol:toStringTag0.760568108091214311: undefined,
      __symbol:unscopables0.76056810809121438: undefined,
      description: "Syntax error",
      message: "Syntax error",
      name: "SyntaxError",
      number: -2146827286,
      stack: "SyntaxError: Syntax error
   at tryCatcher (http://localhost:51158/dist/app.js?v=yJ9KRojv8-WpvAUoTKrlQU3TjmNSInH-YMQzLwKD_0g:6757:9)
   at Promise.prototype._settlePromiseFromHandler (http://localhost:51158/dist/app.js?v=yJ9KRojv8-WpvAUoTKrlQU3TjmNSInH-YMQzLwKD_0g:4779:9)
   at Promise.prototype._settlePromise (http://localhost:51158/dist/app.js?v=yJ9KRojv8-WpvAUoTKrlQU3TjmNSInH-YMQzLwKD_0g:4836:13)
   at Promise.prototype._settlePromise0 (http://localhost:51158/dist/app.js?v=yJ9KRojv8-WpvAUoTKrlQU3TjmNSInH-YMQzLwKD_0g:4881:5)
   at Promise.prototype._settlePromises (http://localhost:51158/dist/app.js?v=yJ9KRojv8-WpvAUoTKrlQU3TjmNSInH-YMQzLwKD_0g:4960:13)
   at Async.prototype._drainQueue (http://localhost:51158/dist/app.js?v=yJ9KRojv8-WpvAUoTKrlQU3TjmNSInH-YMQzLwKD_0g:1689:13)
   at Async.prototype._drainQueues (http://localhost:51158/dist/app.js?v=yJ9KRojv8-WpvAUoTKrlQU3TjmNSInH-YMQzLwKD_0g:1699:5)
   at drainQueues (http://localhost:51158/dist/app.js?v=yJ9KRojv8-WpvAUoTKrlQU3TjmNSInH-YMQzLwKD_0g:1573:9)
  "
   }
```

Comment: You need polyfill for Object.entries(). https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries#Polyfill

Comment: Did you search your code base for `Object.entries`? It could have been added recently. You would need a polyfill as mentioned above otherwise. Easier would be to just find it and replace with non ES6 js if you do not want to deal with the polyfill etc.

Comment: @Akrion I've updated my post as I'm getting a different (similar) error after installing the polyfill. As I said I went back 1 month's commits where it was definitely working. I don't understand why this problem has surfaced all of a sudden. It's doing the same on other machines too.

Comment: @RitwickDey I've updated my original post

Comment: I would first make sure I understand where the issue is coming from before adding another variable like the polifull. Have you tried to see in your package.json if any new modules have been added? It could simply be that your packages version is too open and you picked up a module which added that `Object.entries`?

Comment: Thanks for your helpl @Akrion, I will do a diff on the `package.json` and see if there's been any changes.

Comment: @Akrion the package.json file has not changed for over a month, I was able to browse the app in IE11 last week..

Comment: How did you compare the packages? Do you guys lock to specific version or allow `latest` version on `npm install`? Logically if you are 100% sure that your code base does not have that ES6 code then it just must be coming from a dependency to another module.

Comment: I just diffed the package.json file. Are you saying I need to check each package and if `latest` is allowed, I should lock down the version. I.e make sure every package is locked to a particular version?

If you could give me a clear idea of what I need to do I'd be grateful. I'm less experienced with front-end package management so laymens terms appreciated!

Thanks, Nick

Comment: @VinylWarmth yes lock the packages that allow latest, delete node_modules folder and run *npm install*. If nothing helps, start removing *your* modules selectively if you can, until you narrow down and nail the culprit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As people have mentioned, the fix for this was to implement the following polyfill

```
if (!Object.entries)
        Object.entries = function (obj) {
            var ownProps = Object.keys(obj),
                i = ownProps.length,
                resArray = new Array(i); // preallocate the Array
            while (i--)
                resArray[i] = [ownProps[i], obj[ownProps[i]]];

            return resArray;
        };
```

Comment: Link to the original source => https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries#Polyfill